# curl is not grabbing every Facebook source code

Tags: php, html, facebook, curl

I have this simple php curl code that gets a html source code from a facebook page, but it is not working for all of them.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://www.facebook.com/viktor.milosevic.311?fref=ts");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0 en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$data = curl_exec( $ch );
echo $data;
?>
```

The code above will show the source code for the link in the example, but for some links I get no source code, for example for the link: https://www.facebook.com/sandra.usic?fref=ts

What I get instead of the page source code is

> The link you followed may have expired, or the page may only be visible to an audience you're not in.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow scraping without written permission from them. That you can read at https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php?hc_location=ufi

Comment: Most likely explanation is that the specified profile is not public. The fix is to accept that people want their privacy respected.

Comment: if you can do it manually and it will show you the source code, it means you can do it with curl, and it works, but what is so special with some pages? also the one in the example is not public, so this is not the problem